# How to edit S3 response header Allow

Tags: amazon-s3, plupload, cross-domain-policy

I'm trying to upload some files inside a S3 bucket with a POST request (using plupload).

I'm getting a `405 (Method Not Allowed)`

The policy is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
      <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
      <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
      <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
      <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
      <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
  </CORSConfiguration>
```

But the response headers are baffling:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3000
Allow:GET, DELETE, HEAD, PUT
```

The Access-Control-Allow-Methods looks fine, but the Allow does not.

I don't get why the Allow header doesn't contain POST and how to change it.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: On what path do you get this response? The root of your bucket? Some sub-directory? I don't think you can expect `POST` to be allowed on any file resource. Also, I don't think CORS configuration would ever affect the allow header. It's meant to control the `Access-Control-*` headers.

Comment: I'm getting it on a subdirectory.

Yeah, I just can't find a way on S3 to modify the Allow header.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? I'm just trying to upload some files inside a bucket directory.
Maybe I'm misinterpreting the cause for the 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Are you posting against the website endpoint or a hostname that's provisioned as a `CNAME` or Route 53 Alias for the web site endpoint?  Because I suspect those don't accept `POST` ... if that's true, you need to use the REST endpoint, bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com.

Comment: Thank you but I'm already using bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was the problem, probably a misconfiguration somewhere.

Fixed it by deleting everything, creating a new bucket and following the official plupload documentation.